# Set option page fro Chrome extension by webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Anybody know how to set the option page for Chrome extension by using webpage (example, from http://something.com/option.html). I can see the "turn off the light" do that. The option page for this extension can be configured via their webpage (http).

If it is impossible to do by this way, can I exchange message from extension with my webpage:

- Write content script just run on my webpage and read all configurations were sent from background script (to load into this webpage).
- Send message from this content script to background script to store configuration.

If can do by first method, it will be faster and easier. However, in the second case, how can I configure multiple content scripts for specific url. For example,

- Content script a_script.js for all domain.
- Content script b_script.js for http://www.something.com/option.html.

P/S: I don't want check domain name and run some code for specific domain in content script.

Comment: Web pages can send messages to your extension's event/background page directly without a content script if you whitelist their URLs, see [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Very useful! Thank you!